# Angular2 not loading nested components

Tags: angular

This should be the simplest possible nested components, but when I load this (via systemjs) all that I see in the browser is "Counters", and the `<counter></counter>` has been added to the DOM. There is no sign of "Hello Counter" or of any processing of the `counter` component.

```
import angular from 'angular2/angular2';

var AppComponent = angular
  .Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Counters</h1><counter></counter>'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function () { }
  });

angular
  .Component({
    selector: 'counter',
    template: '<h2>Hello counter</h2>'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function () {}
  });

angular.bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must specify all directives which are used in your template in [`directives`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/view.ts#L114) property of `View` (or `Component`). See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UkWp389c60jTYYsOOXLx). Correct code:

```js
var Counter = angular
  .Component({
    selector: 'counter',
    template: '<h2>Hello counter</h2>'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function () {}
  });

var AppComponent = angular
  .Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [Counter], // <-- Here we are!
    template: '<h1>Counters</h1><counter></counter>'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function () { }
  });

angular.bootstrap(AppComponent);
```